# How to find the target container while dropping item in angular material 12?

Tags: angular-material2

I am using the angular material 12 version drag and drop feature. I have two connected divs while dropping the item I want to identify whether the source (item dragged container) container and target container(item dropped container) are the same or not.
Thanks in advance. please find below the code

```
<div class="toc_listing" cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="table_list" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="table_toc"
        #list_toc="cdkDropList" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <p *ngFor="let item of table_list" cdkDrag>
            <span class="icons"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <span class="list-no">{{item.tableNo}}</span>
            <span class="list-name">{{item.name}}</span>
        </p>
    </div>


<div class="table responsive-table">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <td>t.no</td>
                <td>name</td>
                <td>type</td>
                <td>population</td>
                <td>actions</td>
            </thead>
            <tbody cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="toc_list" 
                #table_toc="cdkDropList" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
                <tr *ngFor="let item of toc_list" cdkDragLockAxis="x" cdkDragLockAxis="y" class="dragdrop_table">
                    <td>{{item?.tlfTocMasterDto?.tableNo}}</td>
                    <td (click)="viewEditor(item)" data-toggle="tooltip" [matTooltip]="item.selected ? 'Edit Mockshell':'Mockshell is not selected'">{{item?.tlfTocMasterDto?.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item?.tlfTocMasterDto?.tableType}}</td>
                    <td>{{item?.tlfTocMasterDto?.population}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <p class="edit" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editTableOfContent" *ngIf="!item.selected" (click)="editTable(item)"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </p>
                        <p class="delete" (click)="deleteTable(item, $event)" *ngIf="!item.selected"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The CdkDragDrop parameter contains the container (dropped container) and previousContainer which you can compare directly

```js
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
  if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
   ...your logic
  }
}
```

Comment: already tried this but not working some times

Comment: can you add a little more detail like does CdkDragDrop parameter not have previousContainer and container or are the elements incorrect?  and when you say sometimes are there any specific scenarios where this does not work?